# Firemonkey form - MainMenu dissapears when Maximize button is off

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

How do I show `TMainMenu` on `Firemonkey` form when `Form.BorderIcons.biMaximize` is `false`? When I set it to `false`, `MainMenu` doesn't show up... and when it is set to `true`, it does.

Comment: It's as if FMX was written and nobody thought to test it .......  Time for a QC report.

Comment: It's actually worse than that; remove any of the BorderIcons and the menu doesn't show up.

Comment: Or use one of the premium styles and maximize doesn't work (QCed) - XE6. Or use blend.style and the buttons provide no feedback when pressed.

Comment: Why didn't they fix that?

Comment: I know the issue with the premium styles has been reported more than once on QC.

Comment: I just installed XE6 Update 1 and it fixes the problem with faulty maximize button when using the premium styles. Also in the blend style the buttons now show some feedback when pressed, though it is still a bit subtle.

Comment: You mean HOTFIX1 ? It doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this does not appear to work when `biMaximize`, `biMinimize` or `biSystem` are `False`. It looks like a bug to me. Although I suppose it could be by design. If I were you I would submit a bug report.

In the meantime, use a `TMenuBar` component instead.

Comment: I'm a bit shocked that noone checked it out in software that costs more than 4000 EUR per license.

Comment: I'm not. FMX is a bug factory. The quality of Delphi libraries has been dire for many years now. FMX plumbs new depths.

Comment: No, those were the halcyon days. Anyway, I'm not sure there's very much more to say here.